# Writing ProcessParameters during build

Tags: tfs, build, workflow-foundation-4

My TFS2012 custom build workflow has many custom parameters, which are defined in my build definition. I want to pass all of them to an exe that runs during build (I'm aware of the option of custom activities, but I can't use it, since I don't want to change the controller's binaries every time).

I managed to take `buildDetail.ProcessParameters` and `buildDetail.buildDefinition.ProcessParameters`, write them to files and pass them to my exe, which will parse them (possibly using [`WorkflowHelpers.DeserializeProcessParameters`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg433787.aspx). However, this means that the exe will need to merge both `ProcessParameters`s, and I'd like to avoid that.

Is there any way to get the resulting ProcessParameters from within the workflow? I could call [WorkflowHelpers.GetProcessParameters(Activity)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.build.workflow.workflowhelpers.getprocessparameters.aspx), but how would I get the root activity of the workflow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to do it by keeping a `WorkflowInstanceProxy`, as suggested [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/f4a93463-f2ca-40c2-afc2-ff48d1442f95/how-to-get-the-root-workflow-activity-for-inspecting-the-children-activities?forum=wfprerelease):

```
public class WriteProcessParameters : CodeActivity
{
    protected override void Execute(CodeActivityContext context)
    {
        WorkflowInstanceProxy proxy = context.GetExtension<WorkflowInstanceInfo>().GetProxy();
        Activity root = proxy.WorkflowDefinition;
        Dictionary<string, ProcessParameter> processParams = WorkflowHelpers.GetProcessParameters(root);
        // Serialize processParams somehow...
    }

    protected override void CacheMetadata(CodeActivityMetadata metadata)
    {
        base.CacheMetadata(metadata);
        metadata.AddDefaultExtensionProvider<WorkflowInstanceInfo>(() => new WorkflowInstanceInfo());
    }

    private class WorkflowInstanceInfo : IWorkflowInstanceExtension
    {
        private WorkflowInstanceProxy m_proxy;
        public IEnumerable<object> GetAdditionalExtensions() { yield break; }
        public void SetInstance(WorkflowInstanceProxy instance) { this.m_proxy = instance; }
        public WorkflowInstanceProxy GetProxy() { return m_proxy; }
    }
}
```

That worked in my toy test, but not in an actual workflow (not sure why). So I ended up reading properties, like this:

```
public InArgument<string> Filename { get; set; }

protected override void Execute(CodeActivityContext context)
{
    var propDescriptors = context.DataContext.GetProperties().Cast<PropertyDescriptor>();
    var props = new Dictionary<string, object>();
    foreach (var propDesc in propDescriptors.OrderBy(p => p.Name))
    {
        object value = propDesc.GetValue(context.DataContext);
        if (value == null)
        {
            var converter = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(propDesc.PropertyType);
            if (converter.CanConvertTo(propDesc.PropertyType))
            {
                value = converter.ConvertTo(value, propDesc.PropertyType); // Known case: null string
            }
            else
            {
                continue;  // Known case: RunTestParameters
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (!value.GetType().IsVisible || !value.GetType().IsSerializable)
            {
                continue;
            }
        }

        props.Add(propDesc.Name, value);
    }

    File.WriteAllText(Filename.Get(context), WorkflowHelpers.SerializeProcessParameters(props));
}
```